# Oracle SQL - What kind of data types that support "contain images"?

Tags: sql, image, oracle, attributes

I'm an SQL beginner learner and this week I have an SQL homework that tells me to create a `FOOTBALL_TEAM` table which contains these attributes:

- ID: number, 3 digits
- Name: varchar, not null
- **National Flag: contains (store) 1 image, not null**
- Number of champions: integer, non negative

At this moment I have no idea that any of the data types in SQL support "contain images". Can anybody show me the proper way to declare the `National Flag` attribute above ? *(and how to add images to that attribute later ?)*

Any comments would be very appreciated. Thanks a lot !

Comment: What is the field `NationalFlag` supposed to store?

Comment: it supposed to store 1 image @@

Comment: @rainmain_TS7 . . . The word "flag" often means a binary flag column.  In any case, read about BLOBs at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT513.